# Flutter Navigator.pop won't send data back

Tags: android-studio, flutter

This is my code so far. I dont know whats wrong, I tried a lots of youtube turolial and other things as well, but its looks like the pop wont give back the correct data. I really need help, i spend 2 days already

```
void main() {
  List<String> names = [];
  List<String> mgs = [];

  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'Returning Data',
    home: HomeScreen(names, mgs),
  ));
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  List<String> names = [];
  List<String> mgs = [];

  HomeScreen(this.names, this.mgs);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        title: Text("Project_Drink"),

      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Expanded(
                child:  ListView.builder
                  (
                    itemCount: mgs.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, Index) {
                      return Text("Name: " + names[Index]
                          +" "+ "Mg: " + mgs[Index]);
                    }
                )
            )


          ],

        ),


      ),


      bottomNavigationBar :BottomAppBar  (

        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              const Expanded(child: Text("TOTAL : 200")),
              FloatingActionButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AddProduct()),
                  );
                },
                child: Icon(Icons.add),

              ),


            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),

    );
  }

}
```

This is the AddProduct i want this to send back the data and then i should be able to put in into a list.Lika a not pad

```
class AddProduct extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => new _AddProductState();
}


class _AddProductState extends State<AddProduct> {
  List<String> names = [];
  List<String> mgs = [];


  //final TextEditingController eCtrl = new TextEditingController();
  final nameController = TextEditingController();
  final mgController = TextEditingController();


  @override
  Widget build (BuildContext ctxt) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          title: Text("New Drink"),

        ),

        body: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: "Name",
              ),
              controller: nameController,

            ),

            new TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: "Mg",
                suffixText: "Mg",
              ),
              controller: mgController,

            ),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: (){
                names.add(nameController.text);
                mgs.add(mgController.text);
                setState(() {});
                nameController.clear();
                mgController.clear();
                Navigator.pop(context, names + mgs);

              },
              child: Text("ADD"),

            ),

          ],
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: looks like you are not storing the returned value; something like `onPressed:() async{ var r =await Navigator.push(...); print(r);}`

Comment: check the official example https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/returning-data

Answer (score 0):

I moved your lists to `HomeScreen` widget instead of `main` function. Your main function should just run the app

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      title: 'Returning Data',
      home: HomeScreen(),
    ),
  );
}
```

And I convert your `HomeScreen` widget to `StatefulWidget` insted of `StatelessWidget` because when you add new items and display it screen your state will change and `StatelessWidget` is not able to do that. It will be something like that

`Navigator.push` returns a future value so if you want to declare a variable with the data comes from that, you need to await for it. After you get the data you can add them into your lists but it needs to be inside `setState` function to update UI

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  List<String> names = [];
  List<String> mgs = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        title: Text("Project_Drink"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Expanded(
                child:  ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: mgs.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Text("Name: " + names[index] + " " + "Mg: " + mgs[index]);
                  }
                ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(child: Text("TOTAL : 200")),
              FloatingActionButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  // Navigator.push returns a future value so you need to await for it 
                  var data = await Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AddProduct()),
                  );
                  // After you get the data from the other page you need to add them into your lists inside setState function to update UI
                  setState(() {
                    names.add(data[0]);
                    mgs.add(data[1]);
                  });
                },
                child: Icon(Icons.add),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I didn't change anything in your `AddProduct` widget.

```
class AddProduct extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => new _AddProductState();
}


class _AddProductState extends State<AddProduct> {
  List<String> names = [];
  List<String> mgs = [];

  //final TextEditingController eCtrl = new TextEditingController();
  final nameController = TextEditingController();
  final mgController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build (BuildContext ctxt) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          title: Text("New Drink"),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: "Name",
              ),
              controller: nameController,
            ),
            TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: "Mg",
                suffixText: "Mg",
              ),
              controller: mgController,
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: (){
                names.add(nameController.text);
                mgs.add(mgController.text);
                setState(() {});
                nameController.clear();
                mgController.clear();
                Navigator.pop(context, names + mgs);
              },
              child: Text("ADD"),
            ),
          ],
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Although this code should work as you want, I would suggest you to have a look at some State Management methods such as Provider, Bloc and etc. It will be more effective to create what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

try this one with simple way , when press then call this method

```
 goToView() async {
bool data=await   Navigator.push(context, new CupertinoPageRoute(builder:   (BuildContext context) {
  return new CoolForgot();
}));
 print(data);
  }
```

My Next View is Forgot Screen so i have used CoolForgot(), you can use as per your requirement.

then when press on back button in Next View(In my case  CoolForgot()) called this

```
 Navigator.pop(context,true);
```

I have pass bool value and get bool value , you can pass any type of object and get from it.